# python scripts debug in ROS with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, ros, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In order to debug python scripts, I would like to run "source path_to/setup.bash" before python debugger begins. How should I to do so ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VSCode enables you to do this by setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) a `preLaunchTask` in your `launch.json`

What you need is a `task.json` with a `type` set to `shell`. It looks something like this.

**task.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "prerun",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "source hello.sh"  // your shell command here
        }
    ]
}
```

Remember the label "prerun". Now in your `launch.json`, *alt [Launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)*, set this label as `preLaunchTask` like

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python Experimental: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "pythonExperimental",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "prerun"
        },
    ]
}
```

You can tailor your debug configuration for your needs. For the example above, it pre-launches `hello.sh` every time Python source file is the editor is in debug. Now switch to your Python code and continue debugging. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Your method solves my problem perfectly.  :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Perhaps, you can mark this as the answer @JoeyChia?

Comment: Sure.But I am not familiar with the mark function of stackoverflow. Do you mean the check mark at the left of your answer ?

Comment: @JoeyChia yep. That's it!

Comment: When I'm doing this, (preLaunch) task and python file get executed in separated terminals, so the sourcing has no effect. How to fix this?